# Is n:1 observable:observer with generics possible in java? ( observer pattern )

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I would like to listen your opinions about applying observer pattern.

My goal is to implement one concrete observer class that can listen multiple observable.

If I develop each different observer like below, then it would be simple like below.

```
public class ConcreteObserver implements EventObserverA , EventObserverB {

    updateEventA(EventA event) {}
    updateEvetnB(EventB event) {}

}
```

In this case, I should write many different observer/observable classes/interfaces with almost same code snippet inside.

To avoid hassle like above, I'd like to generify observer/ but as you guys know  multiple inheritance rule does not allow code like below.

```
public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer<EventA> , Observer<EventB> {

    update(EventA event) {}
    update(EventB event) {}
```

}

Because I have at least double digit Observable events to observe in one concrete observer, I want to avoid implementing every observer/observable pair separately if possible.

I might guess there could be a better pattern for this case than observer pattern, since observer pattern is designed for n:1 observer:observable while my case needs 1:n observer:observable .

Do you guys have any idea/suggestion for this case?

Comment: `update(Observer<EventA> event)` is a typo, right? I assume you meant `update(EventA event)`?

Comment: If `EventA` and `EventB` could extends a common class you could use generics as `public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer<E extends CommonEvent>` then you would not need to create a method to every observer, just `update(E event);`

Comment: Thank you for an idea, It seems a good way to reduce hassles.

Answer (score 6):

With the magic of Java 8, your `ConcreteObserver` doesn't necessarily have to actually implement `Observer<EventA>` and `Observer<EventB>`; if you write something like this:

```
public class ConcreteObserver {
    observeEventA(EventA event) {}
    observeEventB(EventB event) {}
}
```

then you can use `::updateEventA` or `::updateEventB` on a `ConcreteObserver` instance to get a method that is automatically convertible to the `Observer<EventA>` or `Observer<EventB>` functional interface. For example, you can write any of the following:

- `Observer<EventA> eventAObserver = concreteObserver::updateEventA;`
- `Observer<EventB> eventAObserver = new ConcreteObserver()::updateEventB;`
- `observerRegistry.register(EventA.class, concreteObserver::updateEventA);`

Comment: Fantastic, not only for my case, this will definitely give a huge flexibility on many design.
Thank you for your advice!